# Magento Price Alerts - Trigger on Tiered Price change

Tags: magento

I've never set a store up to use Price Alerts before, and now that I've gone through and gotten it to work, it appears as though the alert is only triggered when a product's 'Price' attribute changes.

This is nice, but what about tiered pricing? Looking through the ProductAlert core module, I am not sure where this attribute is being filtered.

I'm guessing that an additional model, say 'productalert/tierprice' will need to be created, followed by a new method in Observer.php, likely _processTierprice(). Just not sure if this concept is correct... could use a little guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be too difficult; lots of options (it's Magento, after all)!

I'd add new methods to deal with tier price alerts. For products with tier pricing, you'd need to capture the relevant tier data along with the final price (either in a new table or in new columns on the existing product alert table). The alerts are sent out via scheduled job. So, in a nutshell (overrides where necessary):

1. Alter the product alert schema as necessary, and amend the frontend form fields to suit
2. In the overridden `Mage_ProductAlert_AddController` add a `tierPriceAction()` method to process the alert subscription, or adjust its existing `priceAction()` to handle the data being posted in / tier condition
3. Override `Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer` as needed; I'd include a `_processesTierPrice` method() similar to `_processPrice()`.
4. Add a resource model method to get the tier-related prices
5. Add a tier price email block and template (reference `Mage_ProductAlert_Block_Email_Abstract`)
6. Profit!

As a reference for your price logic, see `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`.